# Samsung asks for software update with weird random version

Tags: samsung, ota-update

Today, I suddenly received this update for my Samsung Galaxy Prime Kit Kat 4.1 and it tells me to update to a weird random version which I searched on Google and received NO results (even when typing the 6th letter of the version). I hope this is not a glitch or someone trying to hack my phone.

> **Update details**
>
> Size : 124.17 MB
> Version G360GDXU1BOJ3/G360GOLB1BOJ1/G360GDVU1BOJ3
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a fine update to me. If you check this page on [sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/2015/11/20/11-20-2015-firmware-updates-galaxy-note-4-galaxy-s6-edge-galaxy-note-edge-and-more/), it has firmwares named similar to yours. The final base number is pretty same (`UIBOJ3`).

Besides that, android phones cannot be hacked that way unless you install some real (real) bad app, even then you should be able to recognize such a thing. So I would say just go ahead, this update is fine from security point of view :)

Comment: Thanks sir! This is just a wierd update. First update I seen with a wierd coding number.

Comment: No problem. In any case... I always backup first if I have even the slightest doubt no matter what reason. After all there's nothing to loose... :)